# Installing Jupyter Notebook extensions in JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm starting to use JupyterLab. I'd like to install some [notebook extensions currently available for Jupyter](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions.html), but the docs indicate that [far fewer extensions are currently available for JupyterLab](https://github.com/topics/jupyterlab-extension).

Is it possible to install extensions from Jupyter to JupyterLab? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old jupyter extensions are not compatible for JupyterLab. You can find a list of JupyterLab extensions by searching '[jupyterlab-extension](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Ajupyterlab-extension&type=Repositories)' on github

Comment: Here is a curated list with https://github.com/mauhai/awesome-jupyterlab